# alert not showing up when rendering an action in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, controller, ruby-on-rails-3.2, alert

I wrote the following code to display the `show.html.erb` view with an alert flash message:

```
render action: 'show', alert: 'Please fix mistakes outlined in red'
```

However, the alert doesn't appear.  Notices appear though.  I assume my `render action: 'show'` call above is wrong as I wrote that just by intuition.  This is my html.erb code:

```
<%if notice%><p id="notice"><%= notice %></p><%end%>
<%if alert%><p id="alert"><%= alert %></p><%end%>
```

Comment: are you calling 'render' from a controller action?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A more standard way of dealing with flashes is to write the following in your view layout

```
<% flash.each do |key, value| %>
    <p class="alert alert-<%= key %>"><%= value %></p>
<% end %>
```

and write the following in your controller

```
flash[:alert] = 'Please fix mistakes outlined in red'
render 'show'
```

Comment: setting `flash[:alert]` to my string worked perfect.  So I guess the `render` method doesn't take an `alert` hash entry like the `redirect_to` method does. Why is the `flash.each` mechanism above more standard? Rails' scaffolding mechanism has `id="notice"` messages and devise has `id="notice"` and `id="alert"` notification mechanisms.